# nextjs 9 logout -redirect to login page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I create logout directory in pages which clear cookie and redirect to the login page. when user login successfully, logout works correctly but if page gets reloaded or refreshed, redirect function doesn't work

logout :

```
import { logOut } from '../../store/user/userAction';
import redirect from '../../utils/redirect';

const Logout = () => {
  return null;
};
Logout.getInitialProps = ({ store, res }) => {
  store.dispatch(logOut());
  redirect(res, '/login');
  return {};
};
export default Logout;
```

redirect :

```
import Router from 'next/router';

export default (res, target) => {
  if (res) {
    // server
    // 303:"see other"
    res.writeHead(302, { Location: target });
    res.end();
  } else {
    Router.push(target);
  }
};
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, why do you need `logout` as a page, I think you can just make it as a function and call it from any button where do you want user to click for logout.

And to debug above problem, you may want to try first put `console.log` after ` `store.dispatch(logOut())`. Maybe the `store.dispatch` not called successfully, hence it doesn't go to `redirect`

Comment: I tried all approaches for logout, even call from the button! logOut action just clear all cookie and it works correctly 

 my problem is about redirect function or maybe some config, in case of the page gets reloaded or refreshed, redirect function doesn't work

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the `store.dispatch(logOut())`. Can you make sure that after you reload / refresh the page, the `redirect(res, '/login') after `store.dispatch(logOut());` still get called?

Comment: unfortunately no, I get ( [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 62ms) after call redirect function.Is it related to this problem?

Comment: Ah interesting, where do you have any `setTimeout` method in your application? Probably that's the cause